# Docker: Does container inherit /etc/hosts from docker host?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

In case of I have a machine that running docker (docker host) and spin up some containers inside this docker host,

I need containers' services be able to talk to each other - container expose ports and they also need to resolve by hostname (e.g: example.com)

```
container A needs to talk to container B with URL: example.com:3000
```

I've read this article but not quite sure about "inherit" from docker host, does docker host's /etc/hosts will be appended to container's /etc/hosts that running inside docker host?

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts

How to achieve?

Does this "inherit" has any connect to `type of docker container networking` https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not inherit the host's `/etc/hosts` file. The file inside your container is updated by docker when using the `--add-host` parameter or `extra_hosts` in docker-compose. You can add individual records by using `extra_hosts` in docker-compose (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extra_hosts).

Although if you're just trying to get 2 containers talking to each other you can alternatively connect them to the same network. In docker-compose you can create what's called an external network and have all your docker-compose files reference it. you will then be able to connect by using the full docker container name (eg. http://project_app_1:3000).

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#external

Comment: Thanks, can you give more details in this paticular case: container A, B, C, only A should be in a `bridge` network to connect to internet. A, B, C can talk to each other in a private network, obviously A has 2 network interface. B and C have only one network interface, How to archive this model with docker compose using `external private container network`? If you like I can write another question.

Comment: You can connect containers to multiple networks. One network can be a bridge to the Internet, and the other can be private. Although I'm not sure how you can setup a network that blocks the Internet - maybe if you use alter the container's DNS settings (which you can modify in docker-compose as well)

Comment: I can see we have to setup static ip address for each container to use `extra_hosts` that costs a lot to my setup.

Comment: I extend this question to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52921951/5813693